# validate amount field using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

i been looking everywhere for a solution but nothing which quiet matches my criteria.

i want to enable the user to input any positive numbers with (optional 2 decimal places separated by a dot '.')

i.e: 1.23, 12.23, 123.23, 1234.23, 1, 0

how can i do this?

i attempted to use this regex

```
$('form').submit(function(){

        var amount = $('#amount');
        var regex = new RegExp("^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$");

        var error = 0;

        if(amount.val() == '' || amount.val() <= 0 || regex.test(amount.val()) == false){
            $('label', amount.parent()).addClass('error');
            error++;
        }else{
            $('label', amount.parent()).removeClass('error');
        }

        if(error > 0){
            return false;
        }

    });
```

i am not very experienced with regex, and attempted to use the code above which i found through my search but it doesn't seem to work and i don't know why. i am not sure if it is an error in the regex or the way i am using it.

Comment: What "doesn't work" about the regex you have? What is it passing that it shouldn't pass or not passing that it should pass?

Comment: what kinde of inputfield do you have ? because you can specify the inputfield as number as well. Than your regexp could be way easier. Depending on what you want to do... because not all browsers support all input types.

Answer (score 2):

Use `var regex = new RegExp("^[-+]?\d+(\.\d\d?)?$");` for 2 decimal places(1st compulsory, 2nd not).

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

Note we dropped the sign part `[-+]?` because you stated only positive numbers.

Explanation:

```
^             start of string
\d+           match zero or more digits
(\.\d{0,2})?  match the pattern in the brackets 0 or 1 time

\.            match a literal .
\d{1,2)       match 1 or 2 digits
$             end of string
```

So this allows some digits optionally followed by a `.` and 1 or 2 more digits. Adjust as needed.

```js
var rx = /^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/;

alert(rx.test("1.22") + "\n"         // true
      + rx.test("10") + "\n"         // true
      + rx.test("2223.4") + "\n"     // true
      + rx.test("foo") + "\n"        // false
      + rx.test("1..22") + "\n"      // false
     + rx.test(" 1"));               // false
```

Comment: regex.test(amount.val()) is equal false for any number i enter into the amount field

Comment: @Ahm3d: Then something else is going on with your input. I've added a simple snippet to demonstrate. Do you have padding in your strings? Extra spaces at the start or end?

Comment: dont i need to declare new RegExp before the pattern

Comment: my input field is a normal input type="text". my validation is getting processed on $(form).submit(function(){   });

Comment: @Ahm3d: No, enclosing a pattern in `/  /` create a reg literal. You only ever need to use the constructor if you want to be able to dynamically create regex patterns. For example: `new RegExp(".+" + foo + "\d");`

Comment: i've updated my code so you can see the whole solution i was attempting

Comment: @Ahm3d: Your problem is that your regex isn't what you think it is, and this is a good reason to use a regex literal. You are passing a literal string to the constructor but \ is an escape pattern for a string and you want a literal \. So you have to escape it again. In other words: `var regex = new RegExp("^\\d+(\\.\\d{1,2})?$");`

Answer (score 0):

The regex you've posted allows any number of decimal places. This one only allows 2 decimal places

```
var regex = new RegExp("^[-+]?\d+(\.\d\d?)?$");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's long and ugly and I don't remember where I initially got it but this is the one I use (it validates proper comma separation as well, and allows for optional $ at the beginning):

```
var regex = /^\$?(([1-9][0-9]{0,2}(,[0-9]{3})*)|[0-9]+)?(.[0-9]{2})?$/;
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5v9zcxrm/5/

For the decimal places I use (.[0-9]{2}) to only validate 2 decimal places or zero. if you want to allow one decimal place use:

```
var regex = /^\$?(([1-9][0-9]{0,2}(,[0-9]{3})*)|[0-9]+)?(.[0-9]{1,2})?$/;
```

If all you need is numbers (with no commas) and a possible decimal of one or two digits use:

```
var regex = /^\d+(.[0-9]{1,2})?$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').submit(function(){

        var amount = $('#amount');
        var regex = /^\d+(\.\d{2,2})?$/;

        var error = 0;

        if(amount.val() == '' || amount.val() <= 0 || regex.test(amount.val()) == false){
            $('label', amount.parent()).addClass('error');
            error++;
        }else{
            $('label', amount.parent()).removeClass('error');
        }

        if(error > 0){
            return false;
        }

    });
```

this is my updated solution which works as intended. special thanks to Matt Burland and everyone who made this possible